# Accessing objects in array with other objects and their Values.Squareup returned Object api

Tags: php, arrays, object

How do I access the values in the square up api return object.

usually I would do:$result is holding the object array

```
echo $result->id;
```

but this does not appear to be working:

Object Returned When using print_r()

```
SquareConnect\Model\ChargeResponse Object
(
    [errors:protected] => 
    [transaction:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Transaction Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 1111111-15f3-5b37-6940-ceac7a6b54b8 //modified for stackoverflow
            [location_id:protected] => 111111111111111111111111111111 //modified
            [created_at:protected] => 2017-02-17T22:48:15Z
            [tenders:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SquareConnect\Model\Tender Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => 111111-3e5f-1111111-710c-4a4f11111d7be //modified for stack overflow
                            [location_id:protected] => 111111Nz8yXzf7rZHFYx0mbIKEgAQ //modified for stack overflow
                            [transaction_id:protected] => 111111111-15f3-5b37-6940-11111 //modified for stack overflow
                            [created_at:protected] => 2017-02-17T22:48:15Z
                            [note:protected] => Online Transaction
                            [amount_money:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Money Object
                                (
                                    [amount:protected] => 402
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                )

                            [processing_fee_money:protected] => 
                            [customer_id:protected] => 
                            [type:protected] => CARD
                            [card_details:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\TenderCardDetails Object
                                (
                                    [status:protected] => CAPTURED
                                    [card:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Card Object
                                        (
                                            [id:protected] => 
                                            [card_brand:protected] => VISA
                                            [last_4:protected] => 5858
                                            [exp_month:protected] => 
                                            [exp_year:protected] => 
                                            [cardholder_name:protected] => 
                                            [billing_address:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [entry_method:protected] => KEYED
                                )

                            [cash_details:protected] => 
                        )

                )

            [refunds:protected] => 
            [reference_id:protected] => 
            [product:protected] => EXTERNAL_API
            [client_id:protected] => 
            [order:protected] => 
            [shipping_address:protected] => 
        )

)
```

When using print($result);

```
{
    "transaction": {
        "id": "9b2f3df1-cdf3-5399-6c54-07a67af8d8f2",
        "location_id": "CBASEGjNz8yXzf7rZHFYx0mbIKEgAQ",
        "created_at": "2017-02-17T23:37:28Z",
        "tenders": [
            {
                "id": "c424e20e-dac0-5144-518a-114fe24cb2e5",
                "location_id": "CBASEGjNz8yXzf7rZHFYx0mbIKEgAQ",
                "transaction_id": "9b2f3df1-cdf3-5399-6c54-07a67af8d8f2",
                "created_at": "2017-02-17T23:37:28Z",
                "note": "Online Transaction",
                "amount_money": {
                    "amount": 402,
                    "currency": "USD"
                },
                "type": "CARD",
                "card_details": {
                    "status": "CAPTURED",
                    "card": {
                        "card_brand": "VISA",
                        "last_4": "5858"
                    },
                    "entry_method": "KEYED"
                }
            }
        ],
        "product": "EXTERNAL_API"
    }
}
```

How do I go about accessing the different arrays and objects within the square up api so that I can use this information.  So to keep the answer short, how would I access id or the object transaction id in Tenders Object?

Comment: start here. https://docs.connect.squareup.com/

Comment: @Augwa was already on the developer site.  I got all the code I need to charge the card, but all documentation says is that it will return an array but does not provide any code examples as to how to read the array, which is pasted above.  Hence the question above.

Comment: https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Api/TransactionApi.md#charge

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion and definitely not for insulting each other. Everyone please stop and read the ["Be Nice" policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) before posting anything else.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api did not talk about accessing the returned values so I did some trial and error.  finally find out, that it was a multi-arrary so doing something like  : `$result['transaction']['tenders'][0]['type']`
allowed me to access the values of the returned array.